# How many package.json file should a full-stack app have?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli, package.json

When initating a basic back-end application in node.js (in my case I'm using typescript) one would usually have package.json in the root of their project.

When initating a Angular-cli project one would have a package.json the angular-cli root folder.

When working on my full stack project I used Angular-cli for the front-end, and my question is this, should I merge the the package.json files, or should I leave it be? (this question could be expanded by saying That I'd like to add NativeScript in the future which will add another package.json to the deal)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the projects need to be combined? ....the trend these days is to keep them separate ("separation of concerns")

Comment: Well, they do have a-lot of overlapping node modules which would be install multiple of times if they won't be combined

Comment: Fair enough. You could always give it a go and weigh the trade offs.